# BinaryFormatter from .netCore tries load types from mscorlib

Tags: c#, .net-core

If I use `SerializationBinder` in .NetCoreApp , the method `BindToType` get the typename types from `mscorlib` instead  of `System.Private.CoreLib`

```
    namespace BinaryFormatterTest{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var runtimeType = new Dictionary<string, long?>{{"a",1}};

            using (var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter(){Binder =  new AllowedTypesValidatorSerializationBinder()};
                binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, runtimeType);
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var result = (Dictionary<string, long?>)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
                Console.WriteLine(result["a"]);
            }
        }
    }

    class AllowedTypesValidatorSerializationBinder : SerializationBinder
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<string, Type> _knownTypesCache = new Dictionary<string, Type>(StringComparer.Ordinal)
        {
            { typeof(string).FullName, typeof(string)},
            {
                typeof(Dictionary<string, long?>).FullName, typeof(Dictionary<string, long?>)
            },
            {
                typeof(KeyValuePair<string, long?>).FullName, typeof(KeyValuePair<string, long?>)
            },

        };

        public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
        {
            Type t = null;
            try
            {
                t = _knownTypesCache[typeName];
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException)
            {
                return null;

                // throw new InvalidOperationException("Validation failed, type is not allowed: " + typeName);
            }

            return t;
        }
    }
}
```

So I get as type name

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Nullable`1[[System.Int64, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

instead of

```
[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Nullable`1[[System.Int64, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]]]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, System.Type>
```

It looks like  root cause is in the `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.Converter` class:

```
internal static readonly Assembly s_urtAssembly = Assembly.Load("mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");

internal static readonly string s_urtAssemblyString = Converter.s_urtAssembly.FullName;
```

Has anybody else faced same issue?
Thanks.